# Template filter for generating product by category

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a django project where I am displaying products in the template. What is the best possible way of displaying the product by category using some sort of template filter. For instance, on the template if I want to display Breads by category Hovis. At the moment all the products in the database will be displayed.

```
            <tr>
                <td><h5>{{ product.name }}</h5></td>
                <td><p><strong>{{ product.price }}</strong></p></td>
            </tr>
```

Copy of Models.py (as requested):

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
```

Comment: is there a product type like `product.type` of smthing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but this is a very simple project. I have two models, Product and Category. I just need to display using Category via the template filters (if it is possible).

Comment: could you post those models so we now the relation between them?

Comment: Added models.py code

Answer (score 1):

I would send the already prepared data from the view to the template to avoid additional logic in the front-end. You could do something like this in the view:

```
products  = Product.objects.all()

all_products_by_cat ={}
for product in products:
    if all_products_by_cat.get(product.category):
        all_products_by_cat[product.category].append(product)
    else:
        all_products_by_cat[product.category] = [product]
```

And in the template you would just do:

```
{% for product in all_products_by_cat['some_category'] %}
<!-- do something with the product-->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a parsing error: Could not parse the remainder: '['Some name']' from 'all_products_by_cat['Some name']'